# rosdep: no definition for OS [debian]

Tags: ros, raspberrypi, ros-groovy, rosdep-install

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am have installed ros groovy on a raspberry pi running Raspbian. I am currently trying to install rosaria following the instructions online: ros.org/wiki/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA

The installation fails at: rosdep install ROSARIA
I get the error: ROSARIA: No definition of [dynamic_reconfigure] for OS [debian]

It turns out that I don't appear to have the debian definitions for anything, as this shows:

rosdep resolve std_msgs

ERROR: No definition of [std_msgs] for OS [debian]

No definition of [std_msgs] for OS [debian]
rosdep key : std_msgs
OS name    : debian
OS version :
Data: _is_ros: true
osx:
homebrew:
packages:
- ros/groovy/std_msgs
ubuntu:
oneiric:
apt:
packages:
- ros-groovy-std-msgs
precise:
apt:
packages:
- ros-groovy-std-msgs
quantal:
apt:
packages:
- ros-groovy-std-msgs

I get this same error again. Does anyone know to I get the debian definition for these rosdep keys?

I have tried doing 'rosdep init' and 'rosdep update' many times, and have done a 'sudo apt-get update' too, nothing seems to help.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:

Thanks po1, I manually typed in the changes in the /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep-0.10.20-py2.7.egg/rosdep2/gbpdistro_support.py file and recompiled it to generate a new pyc file however I still get the same error when try to rosdep resolve a package, ie:

rosdep resolve geometry

ERROR: No definition of [geometry] for OS [debian]

No definition of [geometry] for OS [debian]
rosdep key : geometry
OS name    : debian
OS version :
Data: _is_ros: true
osx:
homebrew:
packages:
- ros/groovy/geometry
ubuntu:
oneiric:
apt:
packages:
- ros-groovy-geometry
precise:
apt:
packages:
- ros-groovy-geometry
quantal:
apt:
packages:
- ros-groovy-geometry

I've checked the file and I've not made any mistakes in the editing. Do I need to do anything else to make the changes take effect?

Many thanks.

EDIT2: Thanks po1! That solves my problem. Many thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66750/rosdep:-no-definition-for-os-%5Bdebian%5D/) by [wombat_sdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/5251/wombat_sdu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-07-07

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) on 2013-07-10**:
The pull request actually does not solve the problem, I just realized that. I will look into it and push something more likely to solve your problem.

**Comment by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) on 2013-07-10**:
There you go: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/pull/262

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a known limitation of rosdep. At the moment, most external dependencies resolve fine, but the ros packages do not.

A pull request has just been submitted to that effect, you can see it (and try it) here: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/pull/261, if you just need an ad-hoc solution I would suggest you apply the patch referenced in that pull request.

EDIT: The pull request did not solve the problem. [This one](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/pull/262), however, has been tested on a Raspbian environment. You will need to run `rosdep update` after updating the rosdep source.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) with karma: 411 on 2013-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4